# JavaScript switch statement that changes image captions in carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I am trying to accomplish here is a carousel that has a centered image and underneath the image, in a separate div outside the carousel, a quote is displayed pertaining to the image that is centered. I'm using 'slick' carousel and the carousel is working fine. The switch statement goes straight through to the default case.

js file

```
    (function ($) {
        'use strict';
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var $idOne = document.getElementById('1'),
                $idTwo = document.getElementById('2'),
                $idThree = document.getElementById('3'),
                $idFour = document.getElementById('4'),
                $idFive = document.getElementById('5'),
                $idSix = document.getElementById('6'),
                $idSeven = document.getElementById('7'),
                $idEight = document.getElementById('8'),
                $idNine = document.getElementById('9'),
                idArray = [
                    $idOne, $idTwo, $idThree, $idFour, $idFive, $idSix, $idSeven, $idEight, $idNine
                ];

            switch (idArray) {
            case $idOne:
                $('#imageCaptions').html("this is image one's caption");
                break;
            case $idTwo:
                $('#imageCaptions').html("this is image two's caption");
                break;
            case $idThree:
                $('#imageCaptions').html("this is image three's caption");
                break;
            case $idFour:
                $('#imageCaptions').html("this is image four's caption");
                break;
            case $idFive:
                $('#imageCaptions').html("this is image five's caption");
                break;
            case $idSix:
                $('#imageCaptions').html("this is image six's caption");
                break;
            case $idSeven:
                $('#imageCaptions').html("this is image seven's caption");
                break;
            case $idEight:
                $('#imageCaptions').html("this is image eight's caption");
                break;
            case $idNine:
                $('#imageCaptions').html("this is image nine's caption");
                break;
            default:
                $('#imageCaptions').html("sorry");
                break;         
            }   
        });

    })(jQuery);
```

html file

```
    <div id="new">
      <div class="center">

        <div id="1">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1" class="img-responsive">
        </div>

        <div id="2">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=2" class="img-responsive">
        </div>

        <div id="3">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=3" class="img-responsive">
        </div>

        <div id="4">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=4" class="img-responsive">
        </div>

        <div id="5">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=5" class="img-responsive">
        </div>

        <div id="6">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=6" class="img-responsive">
        </div>

        <div id="7">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=7" class="img-responsive">
        </div>

        <div id="8">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=8" class="img-responsive">
        </div>

        <div id="9">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=9" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="imageCaptions">

      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: `switch (idArray)` makes no sense. You have the elements, set their captions.

Comment: I would scratch the variable assignments and try making your `case`  like this: `case $('#1'):` Also, what is the `switch(idArray)` supposed to be doing..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should you the Slick events to change the caption.

Your `switch` was not a bad idea, even if the same thing could be achieved using an array...
The `switch` has the advantage of a `default` caption.

So, using your `switch` within a function called on [`afterChange`](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/#events), it works.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  // Slick init
  $('.center').slick({
    infinite: true,
    autoplay:true
  });

  // Function to be executed on Slick "afterChange" event
  $('.center').on("afterChange",function(event, slick, direction){
    
    // get the "slick-active" id
    var imageId = parseInt($(".slick-active").attr("id"));
    //console.log( imageId );

    switch ( imageId ) {
      case 1:
        $('#imageCaptions').html("this is image one's caption");
        break;
      case 2:
        $('#imageCaptions').html("this is image two's caption");
        break;
      case 3:
        $('#imageCaptions').html("this is image three's caption");
        break;
      case 4:
        $('#imageCaptions').html("this is image four's caption");
        break;
      case 5:
        $('#imageCaptions').html("this is image five's caption");
        break;
      case 6:
        $('#imageCaptions').html("this is image six's caption");
        break;
      case 7:
        $('#imageCaptions').html("this is image seven's caption");
        break;
      case 8:
        $('#imageCaptions').html("this is image eight's caption");
        break;
      case 9:
        $('#imageCaptions').html("this is image nine's caption");
        break;
      default:
        $('#imageCaptions').html("sorry");
        break;         
                     }
  });

  // For the first caption to be displayed on load
  $(".center").trigger("afterChange");

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<div id="new">
  <div class="center">

    <div id="1">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div id="2">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=2" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div id="3">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=3" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div id="4">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=4" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div id="5">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=5" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div id="6">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=6" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div id="7">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=7" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div id="8">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=8" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div id="9">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=9" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="imageCaptions">

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This is great, but when I try to parseInt the active class it returns NaN. I'm just wondering why it doesn't recognize the Id as not being a number?

Comment: I can't say. Console.log what you try to parse to see what this is.

Comment: It's working, I had to change .slick-active to .slick-center. Thank you very much for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

the `switch` statement is like an `if` function. If you want to have captions on all your images, just do the `<figure>` in html and use `<figcaption>` for each image.

To your code, you're basically saying `if idArray is equal to this and that` but you aren't going through the array like you would using a `for` loop. `idArray` can never be equal to just `idOne` or `idTwo`. `idArray[0]` is `idOne`, `idArray[1]` is `idTwo`, etc.

I get you're trying to change the div's content depending on the displayed image.

What you should do is create an array with all the captions like
`const captionArr = ['caption 1', 'caption 2',...];`

Then, find a way to detect which image is active. Take their id, and go,

`if(thisID)` is active, then take the corresponding index in `captionArr`.
For example,

```
let activeID = activeElement.id; //take active element's id
for(let i = 0; i < captionArr.length; i++) {  //go through array
  if(activeID = i + 1) { //since your ids start with 1 and arrays with 0.
    $('#imageCaptions').html = captionArr[i];  //change div content
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful feedback, i will try this later.